# Do brown mushrooms grow faster than red ones?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Early experiments in mushroom farming have resulted in a noticeably higher yield of brown mushrooms than red ones. Is this an anomaly or do brown mushrooms genuinely 'grow' faster?

To quantify, **5 times as many** brown mushrooms have spawned in my brown mushroom farm, which is identical in every way to my red mushroom farm. The brown mushrooms were planted only a few mintues *after* the red ones.

Comment: How large is your sample size? Are the farms located far enough apart (or in separate chunks) that one could be loaded in memory while the other one was not?

Comment: There are 16 source mushrooms in each room. The rooms are of identical proportions and lighting, and are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Get a larger sample size, I think.

Comment: Yeh, it's not a scientific study by any means, just the first time I tried and noticed a big difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. They have exactly the same spawning logic. Each mushroom has independent spawning process. This assertion can be verified with decompiled code for Beta 1.6.5 using [MCP 3.3](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases) where the `mushroomBrown` and `mushroomRed` are initialized in `Block.java` as instances of `BlockMushroom` class with almost the same parameters and the mushroom spawning process `BlockMushroom::updateTick()` is not affected by the difference in instantiation. The specific code is proprietary which I don't have rights to redistribute, but you can still obtain it with MCP and your own copy of Minecraft™.

Comment: Can you show sections of code that prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your description of your test in the comments, perhaps it's related to elevation.  Whenever I find mushrooms in caves they tend to be quite deep, down near the lava layers.

Answer (score 1):

If the coding really is the same, brown mushrooms would grow more slowly under some conditions, as light level is always at least 1 around a brown mushroom. Light level does effect spawning: Though if there are torches the same distance from each, their spawn rate will be roughly equal.

Comment: Not "around". In.